# Installing a python web framework on shared web host without sudo

Tags: python, web-hosting, sudo, web, framework

I have a Cloud Linux shared web hosting service with a popular company. They provided python but not enough libraries for me to run a [FLASK](http://flask.pocoo.org/) micro web framework. I do not have admin access,YUM, or PIP so I can run any install scripts.

What would I have to do inorder to manually install and use a python web framework? 
Does it even have to be *installed*? 
Are there any python web frameworks that don't need to be installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply install the library to your local user account.

To do that see this Stack Overflow answer : [How to install python modules without root access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7465532/1450856)

Comment: Thank you for teaching me something I didn't know at the time